# Angular-UI typeahead show on certain character

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typeahead

I would like to use Angular-UI typeahead directive to do something like Twitter's Tweet composer: show it only when the user inputs a certain character, like *@* or *{*, and when a match is selected, append only the selected value, not replace the entire model.

Is it possible with the current Angular-UI implementation?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I achieved using a custom directive:

http://plnkr.co/edit/9eEq6fOZgVWlhBqUXpV5?p=preview

All you need to do is:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="model"
    typeahead-on="{" typeahead-append="}"
    typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in ['second', 'minute', 'hour', 'day','week', 'month', 'year']" />
```

Comment: This was working for me until I started using the uib-typeahead, now it overwrites what's in the textbox rather than adding to it. Do you know what I might need to change to get it working again? 
I'm on AngularJS v1.4.8 and angular-ui-bootstrap Version: 0.14.3

Comment: Actually this might be a problem with the binding rather than the typeahead itself. I have a dynamically loaded form that's bound to a model, one of the fields is using the typeahead and when I select an option from the typeahead's list, it overwrites the value in the model - but the text in the textbox *looks* fine (i.e. it's added to the end as expected). Very strange! Perhaps I should open a separate case if you're up for helping me out?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is available out the box but the typeahead API allows custom get and format functions to be specified.

[Here is a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JEwHyHOwXFUEQidCzfgw?p=preview) loosely based on the async example in the angular-ui documentation. My version only kicks in when an @ symbol is present in the input value. A custom search is then carried out using the substring after the @ sign.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-input-formatter="formatResult($model)" class="form-control">
```

Controller:

```
var prefix = "";

$scope.getLocation = function(val) {

  var pos = val.indexOf("@");

  if(pos <=0 || pos == val.length-1) {
    return []; 
  }

  prefix = val.substr(0,pos); //cache the prefix
  var search = val.substr(pos+1); //get the search string

  //filter the results
  return $filter('filter')(states, search)
};

$scope.formatResult = function(model) {
  if(!model) {
    return prefix;
  }
  return prefix + "@"+model;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Updated plunk which allows multiple tokens. You can use whatever token matching scheme you want here. This is just an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/RjSZ2wgI1POtNfbQ6tvy?p=preview

Comment: With that solution you can only use @ once

Comment: Fair enough, but it would be easy enough to extend it. Just use val.lastIndexOf("@") instead.

Comment: good approach, but it works weird if you type in the middle of the string

Comment: Yep that is probably the end of the line for my approach. Time for a directive and some nasty caret fetching as per your solution. Hope it helped a bit though.